# Get Rviz to "follow" a point cloud

Tags: ros

In Rviz, we are publishing a series of point clouds (PointCloud2) and I want the viewer to follow and center on the point clouds. Currently, we just have an Orbit view and one has to manually keep moving the Focal Point to keep the data in view. Is there a way to do this automatically? I played around with the other view types, but they don't seem to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You should set your `Fixed Frame` to be the frame of your pointcloud. The other option you have is to set your `Target Frame` to be the pointcloud frame. The ladder will keep your pointcloud centered on the origin which is probably easier.